# How to load a web page from resources in Qt?

Tags: html, qt, qt4, webkit

If we put a webpage in resources, how can we load it in webkit?

Comment: You're still asking nonsense questions. Please learn.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but I suppose you have a web page like a test.html file, and you want it to be loaded in a QWebView. This is quite simple:

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl("qrc:/test.html"));
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

The file has to be placed in a Qt resource file. Remember to add:

```
QT += webkit
```

to your .pro file.