# QWebkit display local webpage

Tags: c++, qt, qtwebkit

I'm working at a browser-like project based on QtWebKit.
It can display any webpage as good as any other browser can, but I can't make display local html documents!

I am using a QtWebView in a QMainWindow and I'm loading pages with

```
view->show();
```

Can anyone tell me what is wrong?

Thank you wery much!!!

Comment: impossible to guess with only the `view->show();` part of your code.

Comment: in fact, `view->show();` is the most irrelevant part.

Comment: May be you should listen first to [`loadFinished`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-5.4/qwebview.html#loadFinished) signal.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't see anything different than loading a normal web page, but anyway this is taken from my answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8020569/how-to-load-a-web-page-from-resources-in-qt/8021096#8021096):

```
#include <QtGui/QApplication>
#include <QWebView>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);
    QWebView view;
    view.setUrl(QUrl("file:///home/luca/mypage.html"));
    view.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```